# Cordova ajax post issue

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on a JQuery Mobile project. Now that I finished the core features, I want to build a native app using Cordova. After installing the project in Xcode described in the phonegap Documentation 2.7.0 the app launches and anything seems to be fine. But after firing a ajax post it returns status Code 0 and a error.
The application is currently working in all common browsers without any problems.

Do you have any ideas? Is it a CORS thing?

Thank you very much,
Flo.

Comment: CORS is not applicable for PhoneGap apps. show some code. specilly the ajax part

Comment: What is that error ? Did you set the external host white list in your cordova plist ?

Comment: The error description by ajax is not the best: "error StatusCode 0" nothing more. My whitelist contains "*" as setting.

Comment: $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : WSURL,
  crossDomain : true,
  data : gsMessage,
  success : function(data) {
  ...},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(bah, I really wanna post comments instead of asking these questions in answers)

I had a lot of issues with this as well.
After a lot of research, I found that error 401 is not returned to Phonegap and becomes error 0.  So my question to you is, does the website you go to require authorization?

If it doesn't, try to change your url to a non-existing one.  I try to go to 'floobaloo.html', which always returns me a 404 error code.  If you can not get the 404 code back, then the problem lies somewhere within your ajax call.  If you do get 404 then you have Authorization issues.

Comment: The website requires authorization(https). If I try google.com, I get a 405(Method not allowed). "http://foo.bar" returns also 0.

Comment: Well, the issue is the code 401 that isn't returned to the ajax call.  The issue is on their Jira ([PhoneGap JIRA]https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2962?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13648218#comment-13648218 )  At the moment I consider the 0 error as a 401 (which is a horrible mistake) and do my work with that.

Comment: Interesting thing is, that with cordova 2.4.0 it still works quite well. But by updating to 2.7.0 it crashes.... How can I do a https POST with AJAX? Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the https authorization (I'm junior developer who works a lot with Phonegap atm).  This aspect is something that is taken care of by other people here.  I have test code with just Basic Authorization header sent through to a test server.